# い adjective + くて + verb

Tags: て-form, jlpt, i-adjectives, conjunctions

I encountered this sentence:

> おなかが**いたくて**たべられません

and got confused with くて. Isn't it used for adding いadjectives? Why is it followed by a verb in the example given? Can I use いたく instead? How will it change the meaning if I use **いたく**たべられません?

Comment: Suspectedly duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3439/7810, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/59575/7810

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12642/9831

Comment: It is not て for of いadj? @chocolate

Comment: @Shiniboi ～くて is the てform of an いadjective. (e.g. いたくて is the てform of the いadjective いたい.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whew. Found the answer. Note C Page 467 of A Dictionary of Basic Grammar (gotta love this book) where it states that the action/state expressed by the first predicate is the reason for or the cause of the action/state of 2nd predicate. Example given on the book : このスープはからくて飲めない.

Should I just delete my question?

Comment: `Should I just delete my question?` -- No... I think you can just accept your answer ... ＾＾