# Difference between using 読点 and て形 when using multiple adjectives

Tags: grammar, て-form, punctuation

When linking adjectives, you can either use 読点(、) or て-form. So I could write the following sentence in two ways:

> くじゃくは、長い、美しい尾を扇のように広げました。
> くじゃくは、長くて美しい尾を扇のように広げました。
> The peacock expanded its long, beautiful tail like a fan.

I'd like to know the difference between these two sentences. I've heard that using the comma sounds more formal, but I was wondering if there was a difference in meaning as well. I'd also like to know if its possible to use more than 2 adjectives with the 読点 and if it is possible to use な-adjs with 読点.

For example is it possible to replace this sentence:

> 奇麗で控え目で優しくてしおらしい女性です。

with this?:

> 奇麗な、控え目な、優しい、しおらしい女性です。

That second sentence does sound very odd to me, so if it's incorrect, is there a different way to do it, or do 形容動詞 require で when linked (even with 読点)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the i-form (usually with a comma) for this purpose sounds more literary than you might be thinking. It's not "simply formal". It's even a little verse-like to me. You can use this pattern sparingly when you want to describe something dramatically or oratorically, but you should not overuse it. Your last sentence is perhaps okay in a melodrama or a dramatic wedding speech, but I think it's unrealistic in an ordinary conversation.

If you feel like avoiding te-forms and want to make the sentence "simply formal", consider using [かつ](https://www.nihongomaster.com/dictionary/entry/19729/katsu) instead.

See Also:

- [What's the difference in nuance between multiple 形容詞 (い-adjectives) with and without て-form?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/63211/5010)
- [Combining two い-adjectives without using て](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11366/5010) (as an exception, something like this is completely normal)
- [Not using くて in i-adjective Conjunctions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/59575/5010)